# pulling variable in the select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to Pull @variable in select statement.

ex:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE
SELECT @STARTDATE = '8/1/2013'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE
SELECT @STARTDATE = '8/31/2013'

SELECT 'Results for DOS Serving' +  @STARTDATE + 'to' + @EndDate
```

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like : Results for DOS Serving 8/1/2013 to 8/31/2013

Comment: Are you getting an error??  If so, tell us what.  I can guess you're seeing "August 1, 2013" instead of the "8/1/2013" -- is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just add string data and dates. You have to convert your dates to a string datatype first. (Also, in your code you never set @ENDDATE.

Something like this should get you close.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE
SELECT @STARTDATE = '8/1/2013'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE
SELECT @ENDDATE = '8/31/2013'

SELECT 'Results for DOS Serving ' + CONVERT(varchar, @STARTDATE, 110) + ' to ' + CONVERT(varchar, @EndDate, 110)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE
 SET  @STARTDATE = '8/1/2013'
 DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE
 SET @ENDDATE = '8/31/2013'

 SELECT 'Results for DOS Serving ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @STARTDATE, 110) + ' to ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @EndDate, 110)
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation as to why your code fixes the problem?